# How Do I Exclude Certain Data Types in a Range in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, unique, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I've looked everywhere for this. I have a sheet that splits a message into columns. It goes something like this.

[On the left column, the message to be split is placed. On the columns to the right the message is split so the person is in 1 column and their number is in the column to the right of that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HraV.png)

In another sheet, I have a UNIQUE() function to gather all the unique names but without the numbers. I do this by doing UNIQUE(FLATTEN()) and manually typing all the ranges that don't have the numbers. My question is: is there a way for me to instead of skipping the columns with numbers and stringing a bunch of ranges together, can I use one range that includes the numbers and the names but also ignores cells that are only numerical values?

Comment: Formulas are written with specifics, and at this point, we have none. Could you at least provide the actual sheet name that contains the original data and the ranges that contain the data?

Comment: @ErikTyler
The function is this in a sheet named "TOTALS": [UNIQUE(FLATTEN())](https://screenrec.com/share/O1jo3Ha9CA).

The message and where it's split looks like this in a sheet named "LOGGING": [Split Message](https://screenrec.com/share/FgXeZ7OLQu).

I had to use every other column as ranges which was time-consuming and tedious. Also, if I want to change something, I'd have to change all the ranges which is annoying. So I want to select the whole range (with the numbers and names) but ignore only the cells with just numerical values.

Comment: You've checked the post and solution by "player0" as correct; and I see that you two interacted on your sheet. Does this mean that your problem is fully resolved now?

Comment: Just in case, I added another solution below, which returns the results in a different format from what I currently see in your sheet after having worked with player0.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The problem was solved, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(FLATTEN(C2:H), "where not Col1 matches '^\d.+'", 0))
```

---

### update:

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(FILTER(LOGGING!D2:Z, 
 MOD(COLUMN(LOGGING!D2:Z), 2)=0))), "where Col1 is not null", )
```

Comment: This works but it ignores all the names and takes the numbers which is the opposite of what I need. Is there a way to modify this so it fits that?

Comment: @Anxietie can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: Sure. [Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16hts1Zuu1dfCm7HEhdNqcSborRtNp9OrxLlX6y1ls4A/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like player0 already provided you with a working solution. I'll add another, the results of which I don't currently see in your sheet.

I added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in A1:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(PROPER(LOGGING!B3:B), ", ", 0)), ":")), "Select Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'Name', SUM(Col2) 'Total'"))`

This produces two columns with headers and all results. It uses only the original raw data from LOGGING!B:B and skips the intermediate data break-downs, going directly from raw data to result in one step.